# AudioKit MIDI Events - basic questions, sending to external synth, not sure about handling

Tags: audiokit

I had some more time to play around with AudioKit, yet I have a few questions about MIDI. I tried googling and I also checked the AKMIDI class reference, but this just further confused me.

Let's keep it simple: I have a UIButton that should give out a "C" to an external synth.

```
import AudioKit
midiOut.openOutput()
midiOut.sendEvent(AKMIDIEvent(noteOn: 72, velocity: 80, channel: 1))
sleep(1)
midiOut.sendEvent(AKMIDIEvent(noteOff: 72, velocity: 0, channel: 1))
```

Obviously this code is spread over the entire ViewController.swift and the sendEvents are inside an @IBAction, but for the sake of keeping it simple, I merged the LOCs.

So my questions are:

1. Will this send out MIDI signals to external machines? (I ordered the Lightning Camera Connection Kit, but it will take a few more days to arrive, so I cannot test it yet.) I cannot get anything from the iPhone Simulator, so I take it, this is not working.
2. Will this send out MIDI signals over wireless MIDI as well? According to what I read on some Google group, you can have Wireless MIDI on macOS. Unfortunately I didn't find anything on if and how you can use this in AudioKit.
3. What about MIDI over Bluetooth? Will this all be handled by AudioKit automatically or will I have to change anything? I read something about midi.createVirtualPorts(), but I am not sure what this actually does. But the word "virtual" makes me believe this is for testing?

Sorry if these questions are ridiculously noobish, but I really am confused by the exact inner workings of this.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test your app with simulator as well. Just run your app on simulator and open the Audio MIDI Setup app on your Mac, go to network settings and connect your simulator. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Audio MIDI Setup]

You have full control over `AKMIDI`.
* If you want to open all available outputs, just call `midi.openOutput()`.
* If you want to open a specific one, like a network session, mostly named "Session 1", call `midi.openOutput(name: "Session 1")`.
* You can get all available destinations by `midi.destinationNames` string array, if you want to prompt a midi dest picker to user, then just open them with their names.
* For closing them `midi.endpoints.removeValue(forKey: "Session 1")`.
* And for virtual outputs, call `sequencer.midi.createVirtualOutputPort(name: "App MIDI Out")` which is useful to send MIDI to other apps living in your iOS/Mac.
* Also, you can subscribe to `AKMIDIListener` protocol's `receivedMIDISetupChange` function to get notified when a MIDI hardware/software available or not to connect.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You seem to know your way around AudioKit/AKMIDI. :-)

My Lightning Camera Connection Kit arrived so I could get into testing.

So far: Wireless MIDI on macOS works most of the time, but the lag via Wifi is always about 40-100ms.

When I use the Lightning CCK and plug it into my Macbook or PC, it doesn't show up as a MIDI device. Is this the standard behavior? And if so, how can I change that? I want to start my app, use the CCK and a standard USB cable to plug into my Macbook/PC and just start sending MIDI signals. 

Is this doable? It seems not. :-(

Comment: Well, there is a free Mac and iOS App for that, midimittr. You can download it from http://www.s-r-n.de/midile/

Comment: Yes I am aware of this. However I just noticed that AudioKit uses the IDAM functionality from IDAM automatically. So there's no need for a companion app for OSX.
For Windows however that is another story. Is there anything equivalent available for Windows?

Comment: Yup, there are several windows options as well.
1) midimittr windows server: http://www.s-r-n.de/midile/windowsfaq.htm
2) musicIO vst plugin: http://musicioapp.com/downloads/
3) midimux: http://midimux.com

All of them are working on both Mac and PC. Install iOS host app and win/mac server app, connect over usb and you are ready to go.
There is a nice post over here covering them all: http://auug.info/wiki/doku.php/midi_over_usb_lightning

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it should. You've opened all outputs, so everything should get the output.
2. I'm not sure about wireless MIDI as there's nothing specifically done with that in mind in AudioKit. If it doesn't "just work" I can try to replicate.
3. You might have to explicitly open the bluetooth connection with openOutput("Bluetooth")

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment to cem: My Lightning Camera Connection Kit arrived so I started testing. 

What I want to have: I want to start my app, use the Lightning CCK and a standard USB cable to plug into my Macbook/PC and just start sending MIDI signals. However the iPad/my App isn't recognized as a MIDI device. I tried Linux, Windows and macOS.

Have I overlooked something or is this simply not possible?

My only focus is getting a MIDI signal from my iPad app to my Macbook/PC. Preferably wired due to latency. I don't care about inter-App MIDI or about receiving MIDI.